# Show Slideshow - Android OutOfMemoryError

Tags: java, android, out-of-memory, viewflipper, android-viewflipper

I am trying to show a slideshow of images more than 50 images. Whenever I run it though, I get an OutOfMemoryError. My code is:

```
public class SlideshowActivity extends Activity {

private ViewFlipper myViewFlipper;
int[] image = { R.drawable.one_facebook, R.drawable.two_facebook,
        R.drawable.three_facebook, R.drawable.four_facebook, R.drawable.five_facebook,
        R.drawable.six_facebook, R.drawable.seven_facebook, R.drawable.eight_facebook,
        R.drawable.nine_facebook, R.drawable.ten_facebook, R.drawable.eleven_facebook,
        R.drawable.onetwo_facebook, etc. };

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {

    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_slideshow);
    myViewFlipper = (ViewFlipper) findViewById(R.id.myflipper);

    for (int i = 0; i < image.length; i++) {
        ImageView imageView = new ImageView(SlideshowActivity.this);
        imageView.setImageResource(image[i]);
        myViewFlipper.addView(imageView);

    }
    myViewFlipper.setAutoStart(true);
    myViewFlipper.setFlipInterval(1000);
    myViewFlipper.startFlipping();
}
```

My logcat shows:

> E/AndroidRuntime: FATAL EXCEPTION: main
>                                                                                          Process: com.applications.codegeek.slideshow, PID: 10126
>                                                                                          java.lang.OutOfMemoryError: Failed to allocate a 52920012 byte allocation with 4194304 free bytes and 31MB until OOM
>                                                                                              at dalvik.system.VMRuntime.newNonMovableArray(Native Method)
>                                                                                              at android.graphics.BitmapFactory.nativeDecodeAsset(Native Method)
>                                                                                              at android.graphics.BitmapFactory.decodeStream(BitmapFactory.java:620)
>                                                                                              at android.graphics.BitmapFactory.decodeResourceStream(BitmapFactory.java:455)
>                                                                                              at android.graphics.drawable.Drawable.createFromResourceStream(Drawable.java:1155)
>                                                                                              at android.content.res.ResourcesImpl.loadDrawableForCookie(ResourcesImpl.java:720)
>                                                                                              at android.content.res.ResourcesImpl.loadDrawable(ResourcesImpl.java:571)
>                                                                                              at android.content.res.Resources.getDrawable(Resources.java:771)
>                                                                                              at android.content.Context.getDrawable(Context.java:525)
>                                                                                              at android.widget.ImageView.resolveUri(ImageView.java:856)
>                                                                                              at android.widget.ImageView.setImageResource(ImageView.java:448)
>                                                                                              at com.applications.codegeek.slideshow.SlideshowActivity$override.onCreate(SlideshowActivity.java:29)
>                                                                                              at com.applications.codegeek.slideshow.SlideshowActivity$override.access$dispatch(SlideshowActivity.java)
>                                                                                              at com.applications.codegeek.slideshow.SlideshowActivity.onCreate(SlideshowActivity.java:0)
>                                                                                              at android.app.Activity.performCreate(Activity.java:6679)
>                                                                                              at android.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnCreate(Instrumentation.java:1118)
>                                                                                              at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2618)
>                                                                                              at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2726)
>                                                                                              at android.app.ActivityThread.handleRelaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:4519)
>                                                                                              at android.app.ActivityThread.-wrap19(ActivityThread.java)
>                                                                                              at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1483)
>                                                                                              at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:102)
>                                                                                              at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:154)
>                                                                                              at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:6119)
>                                                                                              at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
>                                                                                              at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:886)
>                                                                                              at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:776)

Any help would be appreciated! Thanks!

Comment: why don't you use image loader libraries like glide, picasso etc

Comment: What I found on [Glide For Github](https://github.com/bumptech/glide) was that it is useful to show images. I might have understood it wrong though. About [picasso](http://square.github.io/picasso/) I saw some visual examples about it and what I got out of it is that it is useful for collages. I might have understood it wrong and if so, then please tell me what it actualy does. Thank you!

Answer (score 1):

For reduce memory you can use this plugin
[Android Drawable Importer Plugin](https://github.com/winterDroid/android-drawable-importer-intellij-plugin)

And too..

android:largeHeap="true" in your Manifest
It will increase your heap size and avoid the OutOfMemory

Good luck!

Comment: Its still not working. I already had the largeHeap in my manifest but I converted all my images to ldpi but it still shows this error. Please help

Comment: try with put in your gradle dexOptions       android {
    compileSdkVersion 25
    buildToolsVersion '23.0.3'
    dexOptions {
        preDexLibraries = false
        javaMaxHeapSize "4g"
    }

Comment: Nope, I still get that same error. Thanks for trying though.